# Creating an android store

Tags: android

Now I am trying to build a store that associates with google books for my app but I am having this dilemma of how I would be able create a store. Reason being that from my other question on android.stackechange [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20947/android-market-questions/20953#20953).

> Now I know this may sound like a question vampire but is it possible
>   that someone give me a few tips on where to go from here?.
>
> I am really lost on what I should do in building a book/magazine
>   store?
>
> Would I need to get the rights of an actual website that has books for
>   sale to be linked to my android app and make it purchasable on my end?

I thought about this question and I will accept as many negatives this will get but if I get something out of it like an idea or path. It would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good thought about the problem. I just remembered that amazon itself may have an api for their products and google searched and found the appropriate website. [BAM!! got the answer I need.](https://associates.amazon.ca/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)